# OpenApi with external references validation

Tags: swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

Coming from Soap, XSDs, WSDLs universe I am trying to find a way to reuse some of the schemas defined while using OpenApi v3.

Directory structure:

[image]

Address.yaml

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: An include file to define an address
  version: 1.0.0
paths: {}
components:
  schemas:
    Address:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        streetName:
          type: string
        streetNumber:
          type: integer
          format: int32
        city:
          type: string
        postalCode:
          type: string
          format: date-time
        country:
          type: string
          description: Allowed countries (just on purpose 3 to have an enum)
          enum:
            - Romania
            - Belgium
            - Hungary
```

Customer.yaml

```
   openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: An include file to define an customer
  version: 1.0.0
paths: {}
components:
  schemas:
    Customer:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        name:
          type: string
        address: $ref: './Address.yaml/#/components/schemas/Address'
    Customers:
        type: array
        items: $ref: '#/components/schemas/Customer'
```

CustomerApi.yaml

```
   openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Sample API
  description: API description in Markdown.
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: 'https://api.example.com'
paths:
  /customers:
    get:
      summary: Returns a list of customers.
      description: will return all customers
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A list of customers.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '../models/Customer.yaml/#/components/schemas/Customers'
```

How can I use this structure with existing tools to validate and generate Java code for the Customer API ?

Thanks

Comment: Found a way yet?

Answer (score 0):

Tools for the validation:

1. https://github.com/IBM/openapi-validator

```
npm install -g @apidevtools/swagger-cli
swagger-cli validate CustomerApi.yaml
```

2. https://github.com/APIDevTools/swagger-cli

```
npm install -g ibm-openapi-validator
lint-openapi CustomerApi.yaml
```

They does the validation including the references. Once the OpenAPI will be valid you will be able to generate the code using other tools